# ASP.NET MVC route different domains to different controllers in the same project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC, then have 2 domains example:

Example:
www.app1.com
www.app2.com

How I route domain to different controler for any each domain?

[image]

Comment: simple answer. No you cant

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.